# get_users with a value in an array of meta_value returns empty array

Tags: arrays, wordpress, meta-key

I'm trying to query WP users that have the current post's ID saved in a meta_key (training_event_attending) with an array of values.

When I do a **print_r** on the current user's **training_event_attending** where 10, 11 and 12 are the correct post IDs saved to the user, I get:

```
$training_event_attending) = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'training_event_attending', TRUE);
print_r($training_event_attending); 
//Shows Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 11 [2] => 12 )
```

Now if I am on post with ID 10, I want to query all users with **training_event_attending** matching this post ID (10). This is my query:

```
$event_id = get_the_id();   
$user_args = array(
    'meta_query'   => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'training_event_attending',
            'value' => array($event_id),
            'compare' => 'IN',
           ),
        )
 ); 
$assigned_users = get_users( $user_args );

print_r($assigned_users); 
//shows an empty array.
```

I've also tried to serialize **value** and used 'LIKE' to compare like such:

```
value => serialize(array($event_id)),
```

This returns the same user but repeated 3 times.

What am I doing wrong? Can you please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

OK so I found the solution for anybody who is interested:

```
$event_id = get_the_id();
$user_args = array(
    'meta_query'   => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'training_event_attending',
            'value' => serialize($event_id),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
           ),
        )
    ); 
$assigned_users = new WP_User_Query( $user_args );
```